# Refer to Item by Name in Checked List Box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I can loop through all items in checked list box, by index

http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/checkedlistbox-in-vb.net

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
  For Each item In CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems
    sb.Append(item)
    sb.Append(" ")
  Next
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
```

But I just want to check if an item is checked by boolean, and by name.

```
For Each item In CheckedListBox1.Items
        MsgBox(item.ToString)
    Next
```

Loops them.. But I want

`item("myItem").checked?`  or `.selected` properties?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with `SelectedItems`, the checked items are in a collection:

```
For Each item  In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString)
Next
```

There is also a CheckedIndicies collection of the indexes of the items checked.  NB `CheckedItems` is not the same as `SelectedItems`